# Jquery AJAX call: $(this) does not work after success

Tags: jquery, ajax, this

I am wondering why $(this) does not work after a jQuery ajax call.

My code is like this.

```
$('.agree').live("click", function(){  // use live for binding of ajax results
      var id=($(this).attr('comment_id'));
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/ajax.php?request=agree&id="+id,
        success: function(response) {
            $(this).append('hihi');
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Why doesnt the $(this) work in this case after ajax call? It would work if I use it before the ajax but no effect after.

Comment: I recommend having a read on JavaScript function scope - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope and also Doug Crockford's survery of the language - http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a jQuery ajax callback, "this" is a reference to the options used in the ajax request. It's not a reference to a DOM element.

You need to capture the "outer" **$(this)** first:

```
$('.agree').live("click", function(){  // use live for binding of ajax results
      var id=($(this).attr('comment_id'));
      var $this = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/ajax.php?request=agree&id="+id,
        success: function(response) {
                $this.append('hihi');
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: One more thing. Am I allowed to do traversing to it? Like closest?

$this.closest('div').html('hihi');

Comment: Yeah, your new `$this` variable holds a jquery object, so you can treat it just like you would `$(this)`

Comment: great stuff, helped me as well