# How come $(this) is undefined after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, this, undefined

I am doing an ajax request when an anchor tag is clicked with an ID set to href. Btw, this anchor tag is dynamically created.

```
<a href="983" class="commentDeleteLink">delete</a>
```

When the anchor tag is clicked the following code is executed:

```
    $('.commentDeleteLink').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var result = confirm('Proceed?');

        if ( result ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: window.config.AJAX_REQUEST,
                type: "POST",
                data: { action       : 'DELCOMMENT',
                        comment      : $('#commentText').val(),
                        comment_id   : $(this).attr('href') },
                success: function(result) {
                    alert($(this).attr('href'));
                    //$(this).fadeOut(slow);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

When I tried to display $(this).attr('href') it says it's "undefined". What I really want to do is fadeOut the anchor tag but when I investigated the value of $(this) it is "undefined".

What could be wrong with the snippet above?

Comment: `this` within the success handler is the function handling the success, not the original html element you clicked on to the trigger the ajax request. a function has no 'href' attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery AJAX call: $(this) does not work after success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392789/jquery-ajax-call-this-does-not-work-after-success)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax jquery success scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570146/ajax-jquery-success-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
$('.commentDeleteLink').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var result = confirm('Proceed?');
    var that = this;
    if ( result ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: window.config.AJAX_REQUEST,
            type: "POST",
            data: { action       : 'DELCOMMENT',
                    comment      : $('#commentText').val(),
                    comment_id   : $(this).attr('href') },
            success: function(result) {
                alert($(that).attr('href'));
                //$(that).fadeOut(slow);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

because `this` in the callback is not the clicked element, you should cache `this` in a variable `that` that you can re-use and is not sensible to the context

Answer (score 1):

$(this) is called using this inside of the function. Here is the fix :

```
$('.commentDeleteLink').live('click', function(event) {
    var myRef = this;

    event.preventDefault();
    var result = confirm('Proceed?');

    if ( result ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: window.config.AJAX_REQUEST,
            type: "POST",
            data: { action       : 'DELCOMMENT',
                    comment      : $('#commentText').val(),
                    comment_id   : $(this).attr('href') },
            success: function(result) {
                alert($(myRef).attr('href'));
                //$(this).fadeOut(slow);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The context of the `click` event handler (the object that `this` refers to in that handler) is not propagated to your AJAX success callback.

You can capture the value of `this` from the caller by assign it to a local variable, or you can explicitly propagate it by passing `this` in the `context` option to [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.config.AJAX_REQUEST,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        action: "DELCOMMENT",
        comment: $("#commentText").val(),
        comment_id: $(this).attr("href")
    },
    context: this,
    success: function(result) {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");  // Works, since 'this' was propagated here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in the AJAX function, so your have to assign the `$(this)` of the click function to a variable first if you want to use `$(this)` there

```
$('.commentDeleteLink').live('click', function(event) {
    ....
    var current = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        // You can use current here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope change inside the function.

Cache the link object and refer to it inside of the ajax request.