# $.ui is undefined after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following block of javascript in my webpage:

```
console.log($.ui);

$("#schoolBagBtn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"./php/get.php",
        success: function(){
            console.log($.ui);
        }
    });
});
```

And the result of running this javascript is the first $.ui is defined as a jQuery object and the one which after calling the ajax is undefined.
And I need it to be a object too.

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come $(this) is undefined after ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827291/how-come-this-is-undefined-after-ajax-call)

Comment: @kikyalex - I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot, you're right. After reading your comment, I found that that I load another jQuery plugin because of using css framework - bootstrap. After delete it, it works !!! Thanks a lot!!! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue is that something you haven't shown is replacing/updating the `$` variable. For instance, you might have a second `script` tag after the above that includes jQuery again. The second load of jQuery will replace the first, and that means any plugins (like jQuery UI) attached to the first one disappear.